# Spark goodness with Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I've been reading about `Apache Cassandra` lately to learn how it works and how to use it for IoT projects, especially in the need of time series based database..

However, I started to notice that `Apache Spark` is often mentioned when people talk about `Cassandra` too.

The question is, as long as I can use `Cassandra` cluster of nodes to serve my app, to store and read data, why would I need `Apache Spark`? any useful use-cases are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is broad but summarizing ... Cassandra is highly scalable and there are lot of scenarios where it fits but CQL sintax has some limitations if you don't have your schema ready for some queries.

If you want to make use of your data without restrictions and doing analytical workloads with your cassandra data or join with other tables Spark is the most appropriate complement. Spark has a tight integration with Cassandra.

I recommend you to check this slides: http://www.slideshare.net/patrickmcfadin/apache-cassandra-and-spark-you-got-the-the-lighter-lets-start-the-fire?qid=48e2528c-a03c-49b4-879e-45599b2aff34&v=&b=&from_search=5

Comment: I would add that currently the Cassandra connector for Spark does not have  support Spark 2.0.

Comment: @SaifCharaniya No it supports 2.0.0 and Scala 2.10 and 2.11

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.spark%7Cspark-cassandra-connector_2.11%7C2.0.0-M3%7Cjar

In this, 2.11 is the Scala version and 2.0.0 is the Spark version.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is for storing data where as Spark is for performing some computation on top of it. Analogy with Hadoop: Cassandra is like HDFS where as Spark is like Map Reduce.

Especially with computations, when using `DataStax Cassandra connector`, **data locality** can be exploited. If you need to do some computation which modifies a row (but doesn't really depend on anything else), then that operation is optimized to run locally on each machine in cluster without any data movement in network.

Same goes with a lot of other Spark workload, the actions(some function which modifies the data) are done locally and only result is sent to client. As far as I know, when you want to do analytics on top of data stored in Cassandra, Spark is well supported and popular choice. If you don't need to do any operations on the data, still you can use Spark for other purposes like I mentioned below.

`Spark streaming` can be used to ingest or export data from Cassandra ( I used it a lot personally). The same data import/export can be achieved with small hand-written JDBC agents but Spark streaming code I wrote for ingesting 10GB data from Cassandra contains less than 20 lines of code with multi machine-multi threading built-in and an admin UI where I can see the job progress.

With `Spark+Zeppelin`, we can visualize Cassandra data using Spark, we can build beautiful UIs with little Spark code where users can even enter input and see the result as graph/table etc.

Note: Actually, visualization can be better with Kibana/ElasticSearch or Solr/Banana when used with Cassandra but they are very hard to setup and indexing has it's own issues to deal with.

There are a lot of other use cases, but personally I used Spark as a Swiss army knife for multiple tasks.

Answer (score -2):

Apache cassandra is have feature like fast read and write so you can use it with the apache spark streaming to write your data directly into cassandra without legacy.
For use case you can consider any video application to upload video with the help of streaming and directly store it into cassandra blob.